# not blocking in scanf() after making a process active?

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

I am having a parent process 'A' and a child process 'B'. Child process act like a console process, and which is implemented like this ..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>

    int main()
    {
        char inputCommand[50];
        while(1)
        {
            cout<<"CONSOLE>";
            cout.flush();
            strcpy(inputCommand,"");    
            __fpurge(stdin);
            scanf(" %s",inputCommand);
            return 0;
            // here I have an array of commands
            // next i am comparing the input command with the array and getting a number
            // next i am having a swith statement which do some action according to the 
            // input command. 
            // default case is :: no command found!! 

        }
    }
```

In normal condition this application is working fine. But when I am setting up the process 'B' as active
process using tcsetpgrp() or run the process 'A' in background using & to redirect the signals towards process 'B' instead of 'A', process 'B' is not blocking in scanf() and "no command found!!" is continuously getting printed on the screen? Please help me to soot this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @VoidPointer - no, the question is not remotely about C++, but rather about operating system APIs.

Comment: Ideas:  Change " %s" to " %49s".  Usually I do not see issue with cout & stdin, but as you are having issues, avoid mixing C++ cout with stdin.  Is `__fpurge(stdin);` needed?  Note the return value from `scanf()` and if 0, note the value of `ferror(stdin)` which I think will point to _the_ problem.

Comment: output is input/output error ..